# Not in (values) for 2 different columns ignoring NULL value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, where-in

I have a set of values (IDs) and i want to use "not in" in my query

if i use

```
select ...
where ColumnA not in (1234, ...,...,...,..more than 3000 values -IDs)
```

it works but... but returns resultset of row 2.

I have also a second Column B and want to look the query also in this Column

```
ColumnA  ColumnB

1234     NULL
NULL     1234
```

I want that the "not in" looks in both columns but i believe the NULL value make my query not working

I want the result to say ...no row returned

the OR clause doesn't work:

```
select ...
where ColumnA not in (1234) or ColumnB not in (1234)
```

gives back row1 and 2.

Comment: Did you try EXISTS?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx

Comment: should not work... how should the query look like?

Comment: I think if you change "OR" to "AND" you will get the desired results

Comment: Use `ColumnA is not null and ColumnA not in ()`.

Comment: sorry. yes... hard day;-)

Comment: like this? ColumnA is not null and ColumnA not in () and ColumnB is not null and ColumnB not in () ?????

Comment: Why would you use `IN` with just a single value?

Comment: sorry. no constant value...over 3000 IDs to check

Comment: Do you want to return a row with null in ColumnA (or B) as though `null not in (A, B, C, ...)` evaluated to true?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
select ColumnA, ColumnB
from SomeDatabase
where ISNULL(ColumnA, 0) not in (1234)
and ISNULL(ColumnB, 0) not in (1234);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

```
select t.*
from table t
where 1234 not in (coalesce(columnA, -1), coalesce(columnB, -1));
```

This allows you to include the constant value only once in the query.

Comment: sorry i not only have to look for '1234' i have maybe 3000 IDs

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @ids table
{
    id int
}

insert into @ids (id)
values
(1),
(2),
(3),
(4),
...

select *
from table
where
    ColumnA is not null and not in (select id from @ids)
and ColumnB is not null and not in (select id from @ids)
```

Comment: i would prefer something without needing permission to write into database

Comment: and just put my 'IDs' somewhere between this ()

Comment: @sT3v3n: it isn't writing to teh db, it's a variable of type table.

Comment: @sT3v3n: it may and probably will cause 2 reads of the same data. Until you cache it or join.

Comment: sorry for my non pro sql behavior! so i should write my IDs inside...{
    id int
} ???

Comment: @sT3v3n: How you ids table looks like?

Comment: 2 reads of same data would be no problem...performance or "db..answering time" is not the thing...

Comment: its no table... thats my problem... got thoose ids...via excel...lol

Comment: @sT3v3n: is it a variable then?

Comment: i need to write hard..Those IDs need to be included..by writing...unfortunately no table to join....

Comment: 3000 different product IDs

Comment: @sT3v3n: 3000 ids hard-coded into the query? What ever. Save them as `table variable`. See my updated answer.